# How to insert 6 figures in 3 columns each containing 2 figures?

Tags: floats, multicol

I need to put 6 figures in two rows and 3 columns using \multicol, etc. But the numbering should be done for each column as in the following figure.

[image: 3 columns of figure, each with 2 subfigures]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `minipage` and `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package:

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
            \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}\\
            \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}%    
            \caption{Main caption}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
            \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}\\
            \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}%    
            \caption{Main caption}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
            \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}\\
            \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}%    
            \caption{Main caption}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: @fhm: Then use `figure*` instead of plain `figure`.

Comment: @cmhughes Worked. Appreciate you.